# How to use "return this" in jquery plugins?

Tags: jquery

which one is true from below code 1 and code 2 while we use return this?

code1 :

```
   $.fn.greenify = function() {
      $.each(function() {
        this.css( "color", "green" );
        return this;
      };
   };
```

code2 :

```
      $.fn.greenify = function() {
      $.each(function() {
        this.css( "color", "green" );
      };
      return this;
   };
```

Comment: Why don't you try it out? Or at least, read the rest of the [page that you copied this code from](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)?

Comment: Neither of those are working examples. They both have syntax errors.

Comment: What part of your code don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be :

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
      $(this).css( "color", "green" );
  });
};
```

returning the passed collection to make sure the plugin can be chained.
On the other hand, if this is all your plugin does, there's no need for `each`

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
     return this.css( "color", "green" );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the result of `.each()`:

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
   return this.each(function() {
     this.css( "color", "green" );
   };
};
```

See the section titled "Using the each() method" on the [plugin tutorial page](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).